# Read OpenAir File using Python GDAL

Tags: python, python-3.x, gdal, geo, rasterio

I need to read **OpenAir** files in **Python**.

According to the following vector driver description, **GDAL** has built-in OpenAir functionality:
https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openair.html

However there is no example code for reading such OpenAir files.
So far I have tried to read a sample file using the following lines:

```
from osgeo import gdal
airspace = gdal.Open('export.txt')
```

However it returns me the following error:

> ERROR 4: `export.txt' not recognized as a supported file format.

I already looked at vectorio however no OpenAir functionality has been implemented.

Why do I get the error above?

In case anyone wants to reproduce the problem: sample OpenAir files can easily be generated using XContest:
https://airspace.xcontest.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with vector data, you need to use `ogr` instead of `gdal` (it's normally packaged along with `gdal`)

So you can do:

```
from osgeo import ogr

ds = ogr.Open('export.txt')
layer = ds.GetLayer(0)
featureCount = layer.GetFeatureCount()

print(featureCount)
```

There's plenty of info out there on using `ogr`, but this [cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html) might be helpful.

Comment: thank you very much for the quick solution! it works like a charm:)

Comment: @blackst0ne well written Q's make it easy!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately GDAL removed openair support after version 3.3. They moved it to an unsupported extra driver package. More information at https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal-extra-drivers